# How to Re-register Device to Marketing Cloud When Contacts Deleted

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android, react-native

I want to ask if Marketing Cloud SDK (Android & iOS) is able to re-register mobile device to Contact in Marketing Cloud after contacts in MC are deleted? If yes, how should I modify the code?

I have a scenario to delete contacts with random generated contact key, and more than certain days after contact is created --> meaning they haven't log in for period of time after installing app. In this case I want user to be able to re-register their app when log in and set contact key.

I am not going to use "setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)" because before login and set specific contact key, I still want them to have push notification in a specific duration.

Currently I am using react native SDK and device will be registered to contact in marketing cloud when app first installed only (default behavior).

I have done steps as described in the following link:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the GDPR delete functionality inappropriately (the consumer did not ask to be deleted or "forgotten" from the system) to remove a contact then you need to contact support and open a case.  The SDK is designed to honor legal/regulatory constraints and if you tell it to stop communicating, which is what I assume you've done via the contact delete, then there's no direct method to make it start talking again.